# Can I create a cell hyperlink in google that links to another tab using formula?

Tags: google-sheets, hyperlink

So I know I can use the =Hyperlink function to create a link to a website and I know you can manually make a internal link between cells using the manual creation tool but I want to do this using a formula.

I have a script that returns all the names of the other tabs - I now want to make the name in that list a link to that tab.

This is my script

```
function sheetnames() {
var out = new Array()
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) out.push( [ sheets[i].getName() ] )
return out 
}
```

TIA

Answer (score 1):

see this example:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B:B="",,HYPERLINK("#gid=1734824104&range=B"&ROW(B:B), B:B)))
```

[image: 0000]

where gid number can be found here:

[image]

also check: **https://stackoverflow.com/a/58712023/5632629**

Answer (score 0):

**Recommendation:**

You can try like this method on your existing script:

```
var out = new Array();
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

function sheetlinks() { //Add this custom function to return Spreadsheet URL with unique sheet IDs added at the end
for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) out.push( SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl()+"#gid="+[ sheets[i].getSheetId() ]);
return out;
}

function sheetnames() {
for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) out.push( [ sheets[i].getName() ] )
return out; 
}
```

Then, add this formula `=ARRAYFORMULA(HYPERLINK(sheetlinks(),sheetnames()))` on a cell.

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: @Mark Ainsworth You're welcome. You can also up-vote this answer so that other community members who are searching for the same solution will be recommended to your post on their searches.